# This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema

Tags: node.js, graphql

When I start my `graphql` server, I am getting an error as follows:

```
This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.
And it will no longer receive updates.
We recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.
Check out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead!
E:\Training\HandsOnTypescript\Chap9\graphql-schema\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:273
            throw new Error('You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.' +
            ^

Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.applyMiddleware()
```

`

my code :

```
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import typeDefs from "./typeDefs";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";

const app = express();

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema, context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({ req, res }) });
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });

app.listen({ port: 8000 }, () => {
    console.log('graphic server ready');
})
```

please any one help me to understand the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the following line because Apollo Server generates the executable schema from typeDefs and resolvers.

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

Simply pass the type definitions and resolvers to AppoloServer as

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

Make sure that `typeDefs` passed to AppoloServer is generated by applying the `gql` tag to valid Schema Definition Language (SDL) strings.  See [Step 3: Define your GraphQL schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/#step-3-define-your-graphql-schema)